# jquery 'html' is safe with php 'htmlspecialchars'?

Tags: php, jquery

I use jquery ajax and some methods - `after`, `replacewith`, `html`. For all "get" and "post" data i use `htmlspecialchars`. Is it safe to use jquery methods when validate data using `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: It is, but you should *always* validate server-side.

Comment: Safe yes, safe enough, no

Answer (score 0):

If you mean XSS-attack, it makes sense to format the output data:

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Incoming data must be escaped and checked for compliance with the type. What you output to the client affects only him.

**htmlspecialchars** only convert special characters to HTML entities. This function doesn't escape variables.

Comment: Так достаточно для защиты от XSS-атак использовать htmlspecialchars?) Я просто думал, что может htmlspecialchars преобразует в не html, а вот методы jquery преобразуют введенные данные обратно в html.

Comment: @Laravelchik You can use these functions (htmlspecialchars, htmlentities) to protect against XSS-attacks. Don't use raw code output in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For select,insert,update and ... use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
$val = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['val']);
"INSERT INTO `table` (`val`) VALUES ('$val;')";
```

For echo or fetch from database by mysqli use `htmlspecialchars`

```
while($row = ...){
    echo htmlspecialchars($row["val"],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: I use PDO prepared statements